# Filtering nested aggregation result on number of buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query that does a nested aggregation giving me unique `machineid` per unique `key`. What I want Elasticsearch to return is only those `key` with two or more unique `machineid`. I can of course solve this problem application-side, but is there a way to solve this directly in the query? Or maybe I am going about this the wrong way?

My query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": {
                        "term" : { "key" : "" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "keys": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "key",
                "size" : 0
            },
            "aggs": {
                "machines": {
                    "terms": {
                       "field": "machineid",
                       "size" : 0
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example document:

```
{
    "timestamp":"2014-05-23T08:21:51+00:00",
    "machineid":"1444056739053156926",
    "hash":"77f595dee5ffacea72b135b1fce1312e",
    "key":"XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX"
}
```

I have been looking at [scripted metric aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

[Issue #4404](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4404) and [issue #8110](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/8110) on [Elasticsearch GitHub](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch) seem to describe my problem but they are both closed.

Comment: one idea would be to use a filter aggregation at the top levelwith a script on the doc['machineid'].values.size() >1.

Comment: @jilles-van-gurp A script filter with `doc['machineid'].values.size()>1` won't match any of my documents. All documents have a single `machineid` value.